Correlate kafka request-response messages
Scenario:
I have a kafka producer that produces some message to topic A. The message has a dedicated header called correlationID which I want to use to correlate the request message with the response. The response is expected to be received while listening to topic B.
What I want to do:
Once I produce the message, I want to wait for its corresponding response.
The concerns I have:
I am not sure how this can work, since I understand that there are multiple consumers in a consumer group and there might be multiple requests running in parallel with a possibility of committing offsets and introducing the risk of losing messages. How can this be avoided? Is it really a problem? I seem to be confused about this topic and would appreciate some insight.
I thought of using the ReplyKafkaTemplate, but I'm not sure how it works internally. Does it use one consumer in the consumer group? If it works OOB, will it still work in a multi-replica environment (where there are multiple instances of the spring application)?

spring-kafka offers a ReplyingKafkaTemplate class that may meet your requirements. Yes, it should work in a multi tenant environment.

not sure how it works internally.

It is open source....

Otherwise, with a plain KafkaProducer, you can use commitSync to block the sender thread and return a response in the server function

How would it work in multi-replica environment? Let's say I have a topic that has 6 partitions. I send some message to the topic via ReplyingKafkaTemplate. What if the response ends up on some other replica's consumer?
A solution that comes to my mind is to have 1 partition assigned to 1 replica. That way the response ends up on the proper replica. This is one of my concerns.
Another concern is throughput which is important to my application.

Have you tried it yet? What's the exact concern? Replicas do not get records before the leader... Consumers do not read from replicas, by default

You're confusing application replica with partition replicas. I am talking about the environment where there are multiple application replicas..

Same concept? There's only one active consumer per partition. Use a shared database for your application; don't keep data in memory. For example, see kafka streams interactive queries

Not really the same concept. I may have 6 partitions and 2 consumers/application replicas.
In such setup, if replica1 sends a request and replica2 gets a response, then there won't be a correlating action.
Moreover, if I use a database, what's the point of using ReplyingKafkaTemplate?

ReplyingKafkaTemplate isn't a replacement for a database, only to guarantee that you get a response from a producer without explicitly writing a consumer

This is exactly the point I've been trying to get at. That there is some configuration overhead (i.e assigning each application replica to each partition and ensuring that requests and responses end up on the same partition) if you want to use ReplyingKafkaTemplate. Spring documentation also acknowledges this fact, and when you say that it is only to guarantee that you get a response from a producer without explicitly writing a consumer, it is only under concrete circumstances.
Let's close this discussion because it's gotten nowhere.

Okay, well, not everyone has a database to correlate events. If you do, then great. My preferred options would be Neo4J or MongoDB for this use-case with built-in Interceptor classes. Otherwise, if all you have is Kafka, then using ReplyingKafkaTemplate is what you'd use. And optionally spring-sleuth BraveInterceptor. They are alternatives to solve the same problem that you are asking.
